# Golang how to mock aws sns in a lambda integration test or unit test

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, testing, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I want to local test lambda function call and not use aws sns service.

```
func Handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error){
    ...do some logic and db opeations.
    err := db.Create(something)
    if err != nil {
       msg := "something error."
       target := "sns:arn"
       // do sns notification
       sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
       svc := sns.New(sess,&cfg)
       err = PublishNotification(svc, msg, target)
    }}

func PublishNotification(svc *sns.SNS, message string, target string) error {
      params := sns.PublishInput{
                Message:   &message,
                Subject:   &subject,
                TargetArn: &target,
}
      req, _ := svc.PublishRequest(&params)
      err := req.Send()
      if err != nil {
         return err
}
      return nil
}


func main(){
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

Now Everything works fine. And I want to unit test or integration test this lambda handler.

```
func TestLabmdaWithSns(t *testing.T) {
        tests := []struct {
        request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest
}{
    request: events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{Body:"something"}
 }
 
 for _, test := range tests {
    response, err := Handler(test.request)
    // assert something
}

}
```

And I dont want to send sns notification when testing.

How should I mock this svc or PublishNotification function to not publish message to sns when local testing ?


Thanks.

Comment: you can inject all your dependencies in the handler instead of creating their instances inside as an interface and mock their behavior with either [gomock](https://github.com/golang/mock) or with your custom mocked implementation,

Comment: @AkashPatel 
Thank for your reply. That is a really good way to solve this question. But if I cant change these code structure. Any good way to do the same thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use interface snsiface.SNSAPI instead of *sns.SNS in  PublishNotification. Then you can inject mock implementation of  snsiface.SNSAPI to the unit test as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/sns/snsiface/